# Error: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, nfc, mifare

I have that working code in a c# Console Application.

```
using Sydesoft.NfcDevice;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NFCCardReaderTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static ACR122U acr122u = new ACR122U();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            acr122u.Init(false, 50, 4, 4, 200);  // NTAG213
            acr122u.CardInserted += Acr122u_CardInserted;
            acr122u.CardRemoved += Acr122u_CardRemoved;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Acr122u_CardInserted(PCSC.ICardReader reader)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NFC Transponder wurde aufgelegt.");
            Console.WriteLine("Unique ID: " + BitConverter.ToString(acr122u.GetUID(reader)).Replace("-", ""));
        }

        private static void Acr122u_CardRemoved()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NFC Transponder wurde entfernt.");
        }
    }
}
```

Thats for reading out a NFC card with a reader.

I wanted now to implement this in another c# WPF application.
But at the moment, where i just implement the field in the WPF:

```
private static ACR122U acr122u = new ACR122U();
```

I'm then getting that error:
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The type initializer for 'ChecklistenTest.MainWindow' threw an exception.', FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Sydesoft.NfcDevice.ACR122U, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

Anyone knows how to fix that? Or what have to do here.

Thats the nfc reader i have and where i found the code I've tested: https://www.sydesoft-blog.de/nfc-reader-acr122u.html

Comment: Did you install the NFC-ACR122U NuGet package in the Visual Studio project of the WPF application? And if `acr122u` is supposed to be a field of the MainWindow class, it should not be static.

Comment: yes i installed it

Comment: Okay suppose to found the eproblem, I must have created a normal WPf and not an Framework

Answer (score -2):

WPF Framework instead of WPF App